# concatenate query result in a string

Tags: php, sql, informix

I am getting a db result as 3 rows (Please see image link below).

[image]

The sql statement used is

```
select tevmkt.ev_mkt_id, tevmkt.name, tevmkt.ev_id, tevoc.ev_oc_id, 
       tevoc.desc, tevoc.fb_result, tevoc.lp_num, tevoc.lp_den, 
       tev.start_time
from tevmkt, tev,tevoc
where tevmkt.name = '|Match Result|' and tev.ev_id=tevmkt.ev_id and 
      tevoc.ev_mkt_id=tevmkt.ev_mkt_id and tev.start_time>=Today;
```

I will like to use php to concatenate each of the 3 rows into string or maybe use SQL statement.

So, the first 3 rows will display as ;

```
632274|Match Result||Draw||Aldershot Town||Arsenal FC|
```

And the next 3 rows

```
637799|Match Result||Draw||Southend United||Oxford United|
```

Comment: Please learn to use proper `join` syntax and table aliases.  They both help make queries much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [concat](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm)

Sample base on your query

```
select CONCAT(tevmkt.ev_mkt_id, tevmkt.name, tevmkt.ev_id, tevoc.ev_oc_id, 
       tevoc.desc, tevoc.fb_result, tevoc.lp_num, tevoc.lp_den, 
       tev.start_time)
from tevmkt, tev,tevoc
where tevmkt.name = '|Match Result|' and tev.ev_id=tevmkt.ev_id and 
      tevoc.ev_mkt_id=tevmkt.ev_mkt_id and tev.start_time>=Today;
```

Comment: You missed that he wants to concatenate the `desc` column from different rows.

Answer (score 0):

For what I see your model looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tevmkt(
    ev_mkt_id   INT,
    ev_id       INT,
    name        CHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE tev(
    ev_id       INT,
    start_time  DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND
);

CREATE TABLE tevoc(
    ev_mkt_id   INT,
    desc        CHAR(25),
    fb_result   CHAR(1),
    lp_num      SMALLINT,
    lp_den      SMALLINT
);
```

You join `tevmkt` with `tev` by `ev_id` in a **1-to-1** relation.

You filter the records on `tevmkt` using the `name` field and the records on `tev` using the `start_time` field.

Now, you join the `tevmkt` with the `tevoc` by `ev_mkt_id` in a one to many relation, for what I see **1-to-3**.

Your goal is to have a **1-to-1** also. Looking at you example I see three rows for each event and I conclude that they are:

- 1 row for home team, where `fb_result` is **H**;
- 1 row for away team, where `fb_result` is **A**;
- 1 row for result, I'm not sure on this one so I will handle it with care;

If this is the case, you can get your result set straigth using the next `joins` and filters:

```
SELECT
    tevmkt.ev_mkt_id,
    tevmkt.name,
    (
        TRIM(tevoc_result.desc) ||
        TRIM(tevoc_away.desc)   ||
        TRIM(tevoc_home.desc)
    ) AS desc
FROM tevmkt
    JOIN tev ON 
        tev.ev_id = tevmkt.ev_id 
    JOIN tevoc tevoc_result ON 
        tevoc_result.ev_mkt_id = tevmkt.ev_mkt_id 
    JOIN tevoc tevoc_away ON 
        tevoc_away.ev_mkt_id = tevmkt.ev_mkt_id 
    JOIN tevoc tevoc_home ON 
        tevoc_home.ev_mkt_id = tevmkt.ev_mkt_id 
WHERE
    tevmkt.name = '|Match Result|'
    AND tev.start_time >= TODAY
    AND tevoc_result.fb_result NOT IN ('H', 'A')
    AND tevoc_away.fb_result = 'A'
    AND tevoc_home.fb_result = 'H'
;
```